# $upload vs $http for sending base64 string

Tags: angularjs, ajax, upload, xmlhttprequest, base64

I am greenhorn when it comes to Angular - what I am curious about is what is the difference between sending a POST request with $http with a base64 string as the payload versus using $upload. My guess is that $upload sets headers by default that $http doesn't set? Is there any other advantage of using $upload over $http for sending base64 image data?